# How to run React Native app on Android Phone

Tags: react-native

I am building React Native app.

It is working well when I launch the app in terminal on Mac using "react-native run-android".

But when I got the apk file and installed it on another android device manually, it does not work.

It looks like this.

[image: Crash on Huawei P8 lite]

Comment: How can I solve this problem? Anybody can help me?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Looks like the source code in your APK is looking for the package server.

Read this on how to build APKs for react-native: [React-Native - Generating Signed APK](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/signed-apk-android.html#content)

If your devices is connected via cable:

> - If you're on a physical device connected to the same machine, run 'adb reverse tcp:8081 tcp:8081' to forward requests from your device

Otherwise, you can still do this via Wifi by following the last point in the error:

> - If your device is on the same Wi-Fi network, set 'Debug server host & port for device' in 'Dev settings' to your machine's IP address and
>     the port of the local dev server -e.g. 10.0.1.1:8081

Comment: Perfect! When I build a signed apk, I can install it on other devices. 
Thank you, Zidail!!!

Answer (score 47):

If you are connected via cable, do the following:

#### 1. Goto > Settings > About Device

[image]

#### 2. Then Software Info

[image]

#### 3. Then > Build Number

[image]

#### 4. Now Tap (Click) multiple times on *Build Number* to Enable *Developer Options*

[image]

#### 5. Here you go not the Developer Options will be visible in your Settings

[image]

#### 6. Now Go inside the Developer Options and Enable USB Debugging Mode.

[image]

#### 7. Open your terminal

On Windows open **Android SDK Manger > Platform Tools**

Type:

```
$ adb devices
```

This will show you the devices and simulator/virtual-devices that you have on you computer.

#### 8. Forward requests from your device

Type:

```
$ adb reverse tcp:8081 tcp:8081
```

#### 9. Run it

Type:

```
$ npm run android
```

The app should appear on your device

[image]

Comment: This gives me Command failed: ./gradlew app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081

Comment: @Dazzle checkout your [Android development environment](https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup)

Answer (score 4):

Get a list of all the devices:

```
adb devices
```

Then set the which device to run on:

```
adb -s <device name> reverse tcp:8081 tcp:8081
```

Then deploy the app:

```
react-native run-android
```

Answer (score 3):

Please find the below steps to run react-native code on a physical mobile device:-

1. Please make sure you are on the same wifi network(Mobile and Laptop).
2. Run your code and install it on the mobile through the Android Studio.
3. The app will install and asking you to change your "dev settings".
4. Shake your phone and go to "dev settings" and type your machine's IP address(192.16.XX.XXX:8081).
5. Close the app once and open again, in the terminal you will see like this
   [image]

6. wait for a minute app will install and reflect the changes.

Answer (score 1):

If you've upgraded your version of react-native since generating your android project files, you might want to regenerate those now.  I think you can use `react-native upgrade`.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use "npm run start" script.

Answer (score -1):

The following are required in order to run a React Native app on Android:

Android Studio
Android SDK
JDK 8 (installation instructions for macOS here and Windows here)

Answer Source: [Make An App](https://makeanapplike.com/running-react-native-app-on-android-device-emulator/)

We can run the React Native app on Android platform by running the following code in the terminal.

react-native run-android
Before you can run your app on Android device, you need to enable USB Debugging inside the Developer Options.

If you get a “bridge configuration isn’t available” error. Then use below command to solve
adb -s  tcp:8081 tcp:8081

Now re-run the app using

react-native run-android

The command for correcting networking on the physical device should instead be:
adb -s reverse tcp:8081 tcp:8081

When USB Debugging is enabled, you can plug in your device and run the code snippet given above.

**Configure your app to connect to the local dev server via Wi-Fi**

- Make sure your laptop and your phone are on the same Wi-Fi network.
- Open your React Native app on your device. You can do this the same
- way you'd open any other app. You'll see a red screen with an error.
- This is OK. The following steps will fix that. Open the Developer
- Go to Dev Settings. Go to Debug server host for device. Type in your machine's IP address and the port of the
  local dev server (e.g. 10.0.1.1:8081).
- On Mac, you can find the IP address in System Preferences / Network. On Windows, open the command
  prompt and type ipconfig to find your machine's IP address (more
  info).
- Go back to the Developer menu and select Reload JS.

The Native Android emulator is slow. We recommend downloading Genymotion for testing your app.

The developer menu can be accessed by pressing command + M.