# Install application on Android phone

Tags: react-native, deployment, adb

I create an application with react-native-cli, how can I install it to my Android phone?

(Although in development mode)

Platform: osX(10.12+)
target deployment: Android Phone (v6.0+)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to run React Native app on Android Phone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36609523/how-to-run-react-native-app-on-android-phone)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an easy way with Terminal.

in development mode, we run application in android studio emulator or expo or gnymotion with a simple command:

```
react-native run-android
```

this time before running this command, run:

```
adb devices
```

this command will return all of the devices(include android studio emulator) with an id and name.

first, active:  USB debugging option in your android phone
then connect your phone to the computer with USB cable

now run **adb devices** on the terminal.
note that **react-native run-android** command will install your application on one device that exists in adb devices list.
so close all other android emulator and then run again **adb devices** for checking all devices connected to this computer.

now simply run below command and wait for installing it on the device.

```
react-native run-android
```

this will install the application on your connected phone.